# Defining time as categorical variables in decision tree algorithms

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, feature-selection

I'm using LightGBM to solve a time-series regression problem using decision tree methods (determining the price of strawberries over several years). The function [lightgbm.Dataset](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.Dataset.html) accepts a list of categorical features, and I'm not sure if time features should be included in the list.

I've separated my time index data into year, month, season etc:

```
df['year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index).year

df['month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index).month

df['week'] = np.int64(pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index).isocalendar().week)

df['day'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index).dayofweek # Mon=0, ..., Sun=6

df['weekend'] = np.int64(pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index).dayofweek >= 5) # weekday=0, weekend=1

# 1=winter, 2=spring, 3=summer, 4=autumn
df['season'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index).month%12 // 3 + 1

# national public holidays
df['hols'] = pd.Series(pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index)).apply(lambda x: holidays.CountryHoliday('BEL').get(x)).values.astype('bool').astype('int')
```

Now I'm trying to determine which of these should be classified as categorical variables. I've had a look at this [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/17759/encoding-features-like-month-and-hour-as-categorial-or-numeric) post, but it still seems inconclusive.

Answer (score 1):

I already used this kind of temporal variables in the past but I think there is a drawback to use it like that. For instance, take a look to season and this 3 dates:

- January 10 -> winter
- March 19 -> winter
- March 20 -> spring

Which days are the nearest in your case? (10-01, 19-03) or (19-03, 20-03). IMHO, the price of strawberries should probably be closer between (19-03, 20-03) rather than between (10-01, 19-03) even if it's not the same season.

I had a similar problem with DayOfYear (1->365):

- 2019-12-31: 365
- 2020-01-01: 1
- 2020-07-01: 183
- 2020-12-31: 365

The distance between days was not representative. I solved to use this formula:

`Value of day = min((365 - DoY(Day), (DoY(Day) - 1))`

- 2019-12-31: 0
- 2020-01-01: 0
- 2020-07-01: 182
- 2020-12-31: 0

It was the right choice for European electricity consumption because the load is really seasonal.

Comment: I see... so is there a better way to account for seasonal effects if I don't define winter/spring/summer/autumn with integers?

Comment: Have you ever tried dealing with cyclical features like in https://medium.com/ai%C2%B3-theory-practice-business/top-6-errors-novice-machine-learning-engineers-make-e82273d394db? eg. for hourly data, calculate the sin and cos component so that the cyclical feature is represented as (x,y) coordinates of a circle. In this representation hour, 23 and hour 0 are right next to each other numerically.

Comment: No, I did not think about it. My solution for dayofyear is similar but the cos/sin is more generic and clever! Thanks for article.